# Terminate a thread from a web request which was created by other web request

Tags: java, web-services, servlets

I have two requests in tomcat. One HTTP request will create a thread. Client can use a new HTTP request to terminate the same thread.

Is it possible to do that? If possible how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh please, don't spawn unmanaged threads yourself in a Java EE application. Use an [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) with a fixed thread pool. Use [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) as tasks and use [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) as future results.

Create one on application's startup (e.g. in `ServletContextListener` or servlet's `init()`).

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); // Pool of 10 threads.
```

On first request, submit a task to it, get the [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) result. The below example assumes that it's of type `String` and that `Task` is a [`Callable<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html):

```
Future<String> result = executor.submit(new Task());
```

Store this in the session:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("result", result);
```

On any subsequent request in the same session, you could get it from the session and check if it's done or not and if necessary cancel it.

```
Future<String> result = (Future<String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("result");

if (result != null) {
    if (!result.isDone() && userWantsToCancel) {
        result.cancel();
    }
}
```

#### See also:

- [Java concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Thanks thats very useful for me...u mentioned all very nicely...But mine may have different sessions..and different servlets as well..anyways i think i can handle that...Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible under certain conditions:

1. Your Thread should be stoppable. Either by checking a flag in a loop, interrupting the Thread if it is sleeping, etc... Some explanations can be found [here](http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html)
2. You could use the session object to store the Thread and find it back when the second requests comes in. This requires that the client maintains the session (through a cookie or a request parameter, ...). There other alternatives to that.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible

see http://oreilly.com/catalog/jservlet/chapter/ch03.html servlet life cycle

see [servlet with thread](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/ServletWithThread.htm)

see [request](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/211.html)